# Copy data from one workbook to another (tab to workbook)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to transfer data from one workbook to another. Workbook A has 48 tabs of different data and I have 48 excel files that I need to copy-paste to specific columns. the tab name and file names are matching so that is why I set the names range. I keep getting syntax error from the open statement (set y)

and another error at the ws1-select-range line. would you help me to under stand what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub Transfer()



Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim names As String




Set x = ThisWorkbook



For a = 2 To 49
names = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & a).Text
```

' getting compile error: Expected end of statement

```
set y = workbook.Open Filename:=Thisworkbook.Path & "/" & names & ".xlsx"




Set ws1 = x.Sheets(names)
Set ws2 = y.Sheets("Equipment")
```

'updated code as below then getting run time error '1004': Copy method of range class failed

```
ws1.Range("B2:B200").Copy ws2.Range("A3")
ws1.Range("c2:c200").Copy ws2.Range("B3")
ws1.Range("f2:f200").Copy ws2.Range("C3")
ws1.Range("g2:g200").Copy ws2.Range("D3")




    Next a

    End Sub
```

I appreciate your time and advice.

Comment: *I keep getting errors* is an absolutely meaningless problem description. You know **exactly** what errors you're getting, because they're on the screen right in front of you. There is absolutely **no excuse** for you to fail to include that information in your question. You're asking us for **free help** to solve **your problem** - you should provide the information that you have right in front of you to make it easier for us to provide that help.

Comment: `Set y = Workbooks.Open`  and `ws1.Range("B2:B200").Copy
ws2.Range("A3")`  Delete the `Paste` line

Comment: Ken - my apologies. I am fairy new here. Thanks for the advice. Tim - ws1.Range("B2:B200").Copy ws2.Range("A3") worked for two line then it throws other type of error. :-( thanks for taking a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

So I updated some code and I kind of make it work. :)

```
Sub Transfer()

    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim names As String
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim a As Integer


    Set x = ThisWorkbook

    For a = 2 To 49
    names = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & a).Text
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents\Work\" & names & ".xlsx")

    Set ws1 = x.Sheets(names)
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets(2)
    lastrow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
    ws1.Range("B2:B" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("A3")
    ws1.Range("C2:C" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("B3")

    ws1.Range("F2:F" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("C3")
    ws1.Range("G2:G" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("D3")
    ws1.Range("H2:H" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("E3")
    ws1.Range("I2:I" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("F3")
    ws1.Range("J2:J" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("G3")
    ws1.Range("L2:L" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("H3")
    ws1.Range("M2:M" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("I3")
    ws1.Range("N2:N" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("J3")
    ws1.Range("O2:O" & lastrow).Copy ws2.Range("K3")

    y.Save
    y.Close


    Next a
    End Sub
```